# INSERT or Update DataTable values into a database table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table `Cars` as follows:

[image: CarsTable]

This table will be read in grid of a C# application. The application can either edit OR delete OR add a new row. The updated grid will be take in a datatable as be passed as a parameter to the Stored Procedure.

I want to develop a stored procedure which takes `@typeCars` as input.

Now the edited columns should be updated in the `Cars` table, deleted columns should be deleted and new columns should be added.

Please let me know how to achieve this in a stored procedure.

My attempt:

```
CREATE PROC sp_updateDataTable (@dtTypeCars dtTypeCars READONLY)
AS 
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
      DECLARE @dbMaxCarIdval INT;
      DECLARE @typeCurrentCarIdVal INT;

      SELECT TOP 1 @dbMaxCarIdval = id FROM Cars ORDER BY id DESC

      IF (@dbMaxCarIdval >= (SELECT id FROM @dtTypeCars))
      BEGIN
          UPDATE Cars 
          SET Model = (SELECT Model FROM @dtTypeCars), 
              Company = (SELECT Company FROM @dtTypeCars)
          WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM @dtTypeCars);
      END
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
     PRINT 'I am in Catch';
 END CATCH
END
```

Please note dtTypeCars is a TYPE as follows

```
CREATE TYPE dtTypeCars AS TABLE
(
 id INT NOT NULL,
 Model varchar(50),
 Company varchar(50)
)
```

Comment: Keep the question short and describe what`s wrong,dont just dump code with some vague intentions.

Comment: why don't you just bind your datatable to your db and let the change be applied to db directly. using an sp, you'll have to call it on each row update and passing all the values through parameters, then update/add in db

Comment: I think you mean rows not columns for delete, insert, and update

Comment: Merge with a table type as source.  http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL-Server/SQL-MERGE-35.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Merge statement to update,insert and delete the data
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE Cars AS T
USING (SELECT id, Model, Company from @dtTypeCars) AS S
ON T.id = S.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET T.Model = S.Model,T.Company = S.Company
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (id,Model,Company) VALUES (S.id, S.Model, S.Company)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```

Comment: I don't think you need select on @dtTypeCars

Comment: You don't need it, but it's a good practice, similar to the practice of using "select col1, col2 from T" instead of "select * from T" when col1,col2 are the only columns in T.