# How to solve deadlock error in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am facing an error

> Transaction (Process ID 426) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Also sometimes I get this error

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_UserTotalEntry_VoucherNo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserTotalEntry'. The duplicate key value is (89295/37029)

This error sometimes appears. Also I am not able to generate this error again I have tried lots of times. I am trying to insert data in bulk with the help of datatable and created a typed table in the database.

I am showing my code below and request for help and also I am using Go daddy Shared Hosting plan in which I can not alter anything in my database. Thanks in advance.

VB.NET code

```
Public Function SaveUpdate(ByVal Action As String)
    Dim Msg As String = Nothing

    Try
        Dim dt_bulk As New DataTable
        dt_bulk.Columns.Add("VoucherNo")
        dt_bulk.Columns("VoucherNo").Expression = "'" & lbl_vno.Text & "'"
        dt_bulk.AcceptChanges()

        Dim dt_Update As New DataTable
        dt_Update = dgv_manualentryedit.DataSource

        dt_bulk.Merge(dt_Update)

        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()

        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Proc_dml_SaveUpdate")

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberEntry", dt_bulk)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VoucherNo", lbl_vno.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", CustomDate(dtp_Date.Value))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameMasterId", GameMasterID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfitID", ProfitIDNo)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmt", lbl_mamount.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", LoginID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", Action)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceID", "2")

        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 9000
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(ds)

        If DsJantri.Tables.Count = 1 Then
            ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Status"
        Else
            ds.Tables(0).TableName = "PartyDetail"
            ds.Tables(1).TableName = "Status"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ShowErrorMsg(ex, Me.Name, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name)
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

My stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_dml_SaveUpdate]
    @NumberEntry NumberEntry READONLY,
    @VoucherNo varchar(50),
    @date varchar(10),
    @GameMasterId int,
    @ProfitID int,
    @TotalAmt int,
    @CreatedBy int,
    @Action Varchar(50),
    @DeviceID varchar(2)
 AS
 BEGIN
     BEGIN TRAN

     SET NOCOUNT ON;      

     BEGIN TRY 
         DECLARE @CrDateTime datetime = CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30') AS datetime) 

         IF @Action = 'Save'
         BEGIN
             INSERT INTO UserTotalEntry (VoucherNo, date, GameMasterId, ProfitID, TotalAmt, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, DeviceID)
             VALUES (@VoucherNo, CONVERT(date, ('' + @date + ''), 103), @GameMasterId, @ProfitId, @TotalAmt, @CreatedBy, @CrDateTime, @DeviceID)
         END
         ELSE IF @Action = 'Update'
         BEGIN
             UPDATE UserTotalEntry 
             SET TotalAmt = @TotalAmt,
                 ModifyOn = @CrDateTime,
                 ModifyBy = @CreatedBy  
             WHERE VoucherNo = @VoucherNo

             DELETE FROM numberentry 
             WHERE VoucherNo = @VoucherNo
         END

         INSERT INTO NumberEntry (VoucherNo, Number, Amount, ID)
             SELECT VoucherNo, Number, Amount, ID 
             FROM @NumberEntry

         UPDATE numberentry  
         SET number = '0' + number 
         WHERE LEN(number) = 1 AND voucherno = @VoucherNo
  
         UPDATE numberentry 
         SET id = 'BB' 
         WHERE LEN(number) = 3  
           AND number <> 100  
           AND ISNULL(id, '') = '' 
           AND voucherno = @VoucherNo

         IF (@@Error <> 0)  
         BEGIN
             ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
         END
         ELSE
             COMMIT TRANSACTION

         SELECT 
             ut.voucherno AS 'VoucherNo', g.GameMasterName,
             u.UserName AS 'AccountName', ut.TotalAmt 
         FROM
             usertotalentry ut  
         LEFT JOIN 
             ProfitnLossAc p ON p.profitid = ut.profitid    
         LEFT JOIN 
             users u ON u.UserId = p.UserId 
         LEFT JOIN 
             gamemaster g ON g.GameMasterId = ut.GameMasterId
         WHERE 
             ut.voucherno = @VoucherNo

         SELECT 'Entry Saved' AS 'Action'
     END TRY  
     BEGIN CATCH  
         IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
             ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

         INSERT INTO DbErrorLogs     
             SELECT  
                 ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
                 ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                 ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                 ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                 ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
                 ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
                 @CrDateTime AS 'Datetime',
                 @CreatedBy AS LoginID

          SELECT 'Entry Failed' AS 'Action'
    END CATCH;
END
```

Comment: The second error is self explanatory - you're trying to insert a duplicate record which breaks your primary key constraint. The deadlock we can only assist with if you provide the deadlock graph. However I would recommend reading up on deadlocks as they are a large complex topic and not necessarily easy to solve.

Comment: And you haven't told us, do the exceptions occur during the Save or Update condition?

Comment: See if this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282583/insert-or-update-datatable-values-into-a-database-table-using-stored-procedure#:~:text=INSERT%20or%20Update%20DataTable%20values%20into%20a%20database%20table%20using%20stored%20procedure,-sql%2Dserver%20tsql&text=This%20table%20will%20be%20read,parameter%20to%20the%20Stored%20Procedure.

Comment: @DaleK ya error always occure on the time of save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***INSERT INTO NumberEntry (VoucherNo, Number, Amount, ID)
SELECT VoucherNo, Number, Amount, ID
FROM @NumberEntry***

Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_UserTotalEntry_VoucherNo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserTotalEntry'. The duplicate key value is (89295/37029)

Please correct the logic of computing new rows in your table, because of UNIQUE key constraint it complaining not allow duplicate key, when occur occur it jump into catch block first fix UNIQUE key ERROR.